# how to read a file from a directory and removing the extension when printing it in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm building a web app on Django and I've implemented two functions, one to save csv files in a file directory on my PC, and the other is to read these files to view them in the website.

My problem is that I want to read csv files from the directory and display them but without the csv extension, I want their names to be the only thing visible, but I keep getting this error *FileNotFoundError*.

this is the function that saves the files to a directory

```
def openDataset(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'blog/upload_csv_ag.html')

    if request.FILES.get("file2") is not None:
        csv_file = request.FILES['file2']

        if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
            message='The uploaded file has to be CSV.  Please try again.'
            return render(request, 'blog/upload_csv_ag.html',{'message':message})
        else:
            save_path = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Fault Detection App/Uploaded_Datasets/'
            file_name = csv_file.name
            fs = FileSystemStorage(location=save_path)
            file = fs.save(file_name, csv_file)
    else:
        message='no file is uploaded'
        return render(request, 'blog/upload_csv_ag.html',{'message':message})       
    return render(request,'blog/upload_csv_ag.html',{'message':'Dataset Uploaded'})
```

and the function that reads the files from the directory

```
def read_datasets(request):
    path = r"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Fault Detection App/Uploaded_Datasets/"
    test = os.listdir(path)

    path1, dirs, files = next(os.walk(path))
    file_count = len(files)
    print(file_count)

    dataframes_list_html = []
    file_names = []
    index = []
    
    for i in range(file_count):
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(path+files[i])
        print(files[i])
        dataframes_list_html.append(temp_df.to_html(index=False))
        index.append(i)
        for item in test:
            if item.endswith(".csv"):
                os.remove(os.path.join(path, item))
                file_names.append(files[i])

    return render(request,'blog/view_datasets.html',{'files': file_names})
```

Comment: It is complaining that it cannot find the file so it's most likely a path problem. Which line is throwing the error? Have you checked that the logic for the save is correct, and the files are being saved? Also, why are you using `walk`? Aren't the files stored in a single directory? Can't you just iterate through the listing of the directory?

Comment: Take a look at the [Python docs for os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext). That should make it easier to code.

Comment: I checked the path it was correct, and yes the files are stored in a single directory I'm just new to Django so it was one of the solutions that I encountered when implementing the application in the beginning, but I'm willing to learn if there is an alternative for single directories. @2293980990

Comment: @2293980990 even if I iterated through the listing of the directory how will I read the csv and remove the extension when printing it?

Comment: Break down the problem into small steps and check that the code is doing what you expect it to do. From your question, you say you want to pass the filenames to your template, but looking at your code it seems like you also want to read their contents. Focus on getting the file names first, what line is throwing the error?

Comment: I'll expand on how to iterate through the directory in an answer

Comment: @2293980990 ```  path = r"C:/Users/user/Desktop/Fault Detection App/Uploaded_Datasets/" ``` this was the line that was throwing the error, and I was able to retrieve the names of the files.

Comment: That's a just an assignment it wouldn't throw a "FileNotFoundError". If you say that you've check the save logic, then the problem is most likely in `read_datasets`. I just took a closer look, it seems like you're iterating twice over the files, so it seems like you're deleting the files during the first iteration of the outer loop and then trying to access them again. Simplify that to only use the inner loop including the reading csv logic bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Extracting the names of the files

Step 1 : iterate through the directory

A simpler way would be to just do

`for file in os.listdir(base_path)`

Step 2 - remove the extension

You can use the method that evergreen suggested

Step 3 - store the processed string

Just append to your file_names list like you're doing and return the list in the response context

## Reading and displaying the CSVs content

Actually reading and returning the content of the CSVs is slightly more involved, but your current approach by using pandas to read the files, and converting the dataframes to html tables should work just fine. Just remember to return the `dataframes_list_html` list in the context as well so that you can access it in the template